# Not able to play the embedded video into the pdf file

Tags: java, itext

**Issue:** Video Not visible in PDF File Created with iText
**Description:**
I'm using iText 7.2.0 to embed a video into a PDF file. Despite successfully generating the PDF, the embedded video is neither visible nor accessible upon opening the file.
**Code Details:**
I'm utilizing iText to create a PDF document and embed a video file (videos/video.mp4). After confirming the video's existence, I create a file specification using `PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec()`. Next, I associate a `PdfLinkAnnotation` with a `PdfAction` created via `PdfAction.createRendition()`, specifying the video path, file specification, MIME type, and annotation. Finally, I add the annotation to the PDF's first page.

[code snippet where I used the iText 7.2.0 to embed video into the pdf]

```
public class VideoEmbedPdf{ 
    public static void main(String[]  args){ 
        String videoPath = "7ideos/video.mp4"; // Provide the path to your video file 
        String pdfOutputPath = "output/outputwithvideo.pdf"; // Path where you want to save the PDF 
    
        try { 
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfOutputPath); 
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer); 
            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument); 
        
            // Create a paragraph to display video information (optional) 
            Paragraph videoInfo = new Paragraph("Click the link below to access the attached video:").setFontColor(ColorConstant.BLACK).setMarginLeft(S); document.add(videoInfo); 
            // Check if the video file exists 
            File videoFile = new File(videoPath); 
            if (!videoFile.exists()){
                System.err.println("Video file not found at path: " + videoPath); 
                return;
            } 
            PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(pdfDocument, videoFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, "My Video", null); 
            Rectangle annotationRect = new Rectangle(100, 700, 100, 20); // Adjust coordinates as needed 
        
            PdfLinkAnnotation linkAnnotation = new PdfLinkAnnotation(annotationRect); 
            PdfAction renditionAction = PdfAction.createRendition(videoPath, fileSpec, "video/mp4", linkAnnotation); 
            linkAnnotation.setAction(renditionAction); 
        
            pdfDocument.getFirstPage().addAnnotation(linkAnnotation); 
        
            document.close(); 
            System.out.println("PDF with video link created successfully."); 
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Outcome:**
The PDF should contain a visible and clickable link or embedded video for seamless playback within a PDF viewer.

**Actual Outcome:**
Upon opening the PDF, the embedded video is neither visible nor accessible. No error messages are reported during execution.

**Troubleshooting:**
I've confirmed the video file's existence, reviewed iText documentation, and verified the  annotation's coordinates.

**Request for Assistance:**
Seeking guidance on troubleshooting and resolving the issue to make the embedded video visible and accessible within the PDF file. Appreciate any insights or alternative approaches.

Comment: Please put your code as markdown code snippet into the question. Images containing relevant code are not welcome.

Comment: If you wonder why you should include your code as text here: If it were (copiable!) text, I'd likely have copied and run it to reproduce the issue and to determine what is wrong. As it's only an image, I cannot simply copy, paste, and run it in my IDE, and so simply cannot help here.